# Retrofit POST request Multipart and Field

Tags: java, android, retrofit, retrofit2, azure-cognitive-services

**> https://api.projectoxford.ai/spid/v1.0/identify?identificationProfileIds={identificationProfileIds}[&shortAudio]**

> That is the endpoint i am trying to reach.
>
> Params    identificationProdileIds  ===> String
>
> shortAudio ===> Boolean   (Optional)
>
> Headers
>
> API_Key ===> String
>
> Content-type ===> String  (Optional)

Please I am trying hardly to figure out how can i make a request but it fails bad request

**This is my interface method**

```
@Headers("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: 7615c603bcd644cf8a9cd2d8d6cf73c6")
@Multipart
@POST("identify")
Call<ResponseBody> identifySpeaker (@Part MultipartBody.Part file, @Part("identificationProfileId") RequestBody profileIds);
```

This Type of input i pass to it later when i create instance

```
byte[] audioData = prepareAudioData(mRecordFilePath);
    RequestBody requestFile =    RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/octet-stream"), audioData);
    MultipartBody.Part body = MultipartBody.Part.create(requestFile);

RequestBody profiles = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), profiles_list);

adapter.identifyProfile(body,profiles).enqueue   and so on....
```

Before I have such a POST request and i did it successfully but that time without a params 
but this endpoint i have to apply params

This is the logging of retrofit

[Logging the response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6NOnB.png)

Answer (score 1):

I think you want `@Query`, instead of `@Part`:

```
@Headers("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: ...")
@Multipart
@POST("identify")
Call<ResponseBody> identifySpeaker (
    @Part MultipartBody.Part file,
    @Query("identificationProfileId") RequestBody profileIds,
    @Query("shortAudio") boolean shortAudio)
```